# clearTimeOut in debounce and its significance

Tags: javascript

What is the significance of clearTimeout in debounce ?
Here is the code

```js
const saveInput =(name)=>{
    console.log('saveinput ',name);
}

const debounce = (fn,timeout = 3000)=>{
    let timer ;
    return (...args) =>{
       clearTimeout(timer);
        timer =setTimeout(()=>{
            fn.apply(this,args);
        },timeout)
    }
}

const processChange = debounce(saveInput,2000);
processChange("foo");
processChange("foo");
processChange("foo");
processChange("foo");
processChange("foo");
```

Now i tried to comment out clearTimeout and this time foo gets printed five times and with clearTimeout ,foo gets printed just once .I need a clear explanation of how clearTimeout impcats .I understand that cleartimeout is used to clear time but i need an explanation that touches event loop etc.

Comment: It prevents the function from running multiple times.

Comment: i understand this but how .can you explain it in terms of event loop.

Comment: Press a key...wait 3s... press another key within that 3s, clear the timeout and start waiting 3s from 2nd key.  etc.   That's the definition of `debounce`.  Without the clearTimeout, it's just a *delayed* input, not debounced

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setTimeout(x, y)`, you are saying "call function `x` in `y` ms from now." When you call `clearTimeout`, you are saying "nevermind, cancel that."

In this case, you will be clearing the timeout every time you start a new one. That way, each new call to `debounce` will first cancel the previous timeout before starting a new one.

If you did not clear the timeout, then you could run into a situation where the timeouts from all 6 calls to `processChange` would still be active and they would all fire at almost the same time, so you would get 6 separate printouts. By clearing the timeout each time, you will only get 1 printout total.

### Edit after seeing the edit to the question

`setTimeout(x, y)` adds a delayed trigger to the event loop that will fire after `y` ms. Spamming `setTimeout` will add multiple of these triggers to the event loop. If you don't clear them, they just sit there until they fire off and execute.

On the other hand, if you clear the timeout before `y` ms have elapsed, then the timeout is removed from the event loop and it will not end up firing.